# Passing a string variable into a marquee

Tags: string, html, api, marquee

Please help, I am trying to pass a string that exists in a variable I created. It is todo with weather info I am grabbing with an API. This is the variable I am creating;

```
success : function(parsed_json) {
    var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
    var wind_kph = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_kph'];
    var wind_gust_kph = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_gust_kph'];
    var wind_string = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_string'];
    alert(wind_string); 
    gauge3 = wind_gust_kph
    gauge4 = wind_kph
```

The alert works and prints my string. Now I want to pass it into a

```
<td><div><marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left">("wind_string")</marquee></div></td>
```

I have tried many options and can only get what I type and not the actually string inside the variable.

Hope that is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `id` - [`"wind"`, as you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452379/passing-a-string-variable-into-a-marquee/29527193?noredirect=1#comment47257018_29527193) - to the `marquee` element to make it more searchable:

```
<marquee id="wind" behavior="scroll" direction="left"></marquee>
```

Get the `marquee` element with `getElementById` and assign the string you want to its `innerHTML`:

```
var wind_string = parsed_json['current_observation']['wind_string'];
//alert(wind_string);
document.getElementById('wind').innerHTML = wind_string;
```

<sub>Note: [the `marquee` element became obsolete in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0).</sub>

Comment: document.getElementByID('wind').innerHTML = wind_string;

Comment: @BlueCollarIngenuity Yeah, like that. I've updated my answer with the `id` you suggested. Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes I got it working, There was also an error in my script that I had to correct....damn }    :)